# pandas time series different time frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes of time series, one with daily values (df1 below) and one with yearly values (df2 below). An example is:

```
df1                                  df2
Date           Value                 Year   Value
2002-01-01      3                    2002    0.5
2002-01-02      3.5                  2003    3.1
2002-01-03      3.3                  2004    2.7
...             ...                  ...     ...
2010-01-01      4.96                 2010    0.7
2010-01-02      4.98
```

I would like to perform an operation as follows: if the daily date is in the same year as the yearly date, multiply the daily date by the yearly value.

So for example, every daily value in 2002 would be multiplied by the scalar 0.5, every daily value in 2003 would be multiplied by the scalar 3.1, etc.

Does anyone have any experience in these sorts of issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first find [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) from column `Date`, [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) `df1` and `df2` by column `Year` and last multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
df1['Year'] = df1.Date.dt.year

df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='Year',  suffixes=('', '_x') )
print df
        Date  Value  Year  Value_x
0 2002-01-01   3.00  2002      0.5
1 2002-01-02   3.50  2002      0.5
2 2002-01-03   3.30  2002      0.5
3 2010-01-01   4.96  2010      0.7
4 2010-01-02   4.98  2010      0.7

df['Value'] = df['Value'].mul(df['Value_x']) 

print df[['Date','Value']]
        Date  Value
0 2002-01-01  1.500
1 2002-01-02  1.750
2 2002-01-03  1.650
3 2010-01-01  3.472
4 2010-01-02  3.486
```

**Timings**:

```
In [1386]: %timeit a(df1,df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop

In [1387]: %timeit b(df3,df4)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.11 s per loop
```

Code:

```
#length(df1) = 50k
df1 = pd.concat([df1]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

df3 = df1.copy()
df4 = df2.copy()

def a(df1,df2):
    df1['Year'] = df1.Date.dt.year
    df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='Year',  suffixes=('', '_x') )
    #print df
    df['Multiple'] = df['Value'].mul(df['Value_x']) 
    return df.drop('Value_x', axis=1)

def b(df1,df2):
    mapping = df2.set_index('Year').to_dict()['Value']    
    df1['Year'] = df1['Date'].dt.year
    df1['Multiple'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['Value']*mapping[x['Year']], axis=1)
    return df1

print a(df1,df2)    
print b(df3,df4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by row-wise applying dictionary that maps years to coefficients.

Following on the dataframes introduced in your example:

```
mapping = df2.set_index('Year').to_dict()['Value']
mapping
{2002: 0.5,
 2003: 3.1000000000000001,
 2004: 2.7000000000000002,
 2010: 0.69999999999999996}

df1['Year'] = df1['Date'].dt.year
df1['Adjusted Value'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['Value']*mapping[x['Year']], axis=1)
df1

          Date  Value   Year    Adjusted Value
0   2002-01-01  3.00    2002    1.500
1   2002-01-02  3.50    2002    1.750
2   2002-01-03  3.30    2002    1.650
3   2010-01-01  4.96    2010    3.472
4   2010-01-02  4.98    2010    3.486
```

Comment: I think `Date` is not `index`, it is column. Also `Year` in `df2`.